# Do discrete-time Markov chain return probabilities have absolutely summable differences?

Tags: markov-chains, absolute-convergence

Fix an aperiodic discrete-time Markov chain $X_0,X_1,\dots$, with $\mathbb P_i$ denoting probabilities according to $X_0=i$. Define the return probability
$$p_{ii}^{(n)} = \mathbb P_i[X_n=i].$$

> Is it true that
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty |p_{ii}^{(n)}-p_{ii}^{(n+1)}|<\infty\text{?}$$

I am most interested in the null-recurrent case. For transient states there is a positive answer: the return probabilities are themselves summable. I know that for finite state spaces there is exponential convergence to some stationary state, which also implies a positive answer.

Comment: Did you try to compute $p^{(n)}_{ii}$ for the symmetric random walk on $\mathbb Z$ with transitions $i\to i$ and $i\to i\pm1$, for every $i$ in $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @Did: when the self-transition probability is $1/2$ and $i\to i\pm 1$ probabilities each $1/4$, the probabilities are $2^{-2n}\binom{2n}{n}$ which is non-increasing so the differences sum to at most $1$. I don't know about other other self-transition parameters but my guess is they'd behave similarly at least in the long run.

Comment: Right, random walks look like a dead end. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, as shown in the paper "On the problem by Erdős-de Bruijn-Kingman on regularity of reciprocals for exponential series" by Alexander Gomilko, Yuri Tomilov, https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.04357